# How to get rest API of AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-cognito

In our project we are using API Gateway to get authenticated by Cognito User Pool.
Now, we are checking instead of hiting API Gateway can we directly hit Cognito for authenticating users.

So, wanted to check if there is any API of AWS cognito-idp admin-initiate-auth to get the tokens without using the CLI command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the link [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminInitiateAuth.html). You will also find more information about using this API in one of the language-specific AWS SDKs.

For a complete list of all Amazon Cognito API references, refer [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-reference.html)